# How can I finish all Activities in the Workflow in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: 2011, web8.5, workflow

I want to finish all the Activities in a Workflow in onetime by clicking the "Finish All" button.

Tridion 2011 has this function in Workflow (see the picture). However, I cannot find the same button in Web 8.5. Is there any alternative to finish all the Activities (need to select the "Next Activity") in one time?[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the same _next_ workflow activity is available for all the items selected? (worth checking as it's the one that always got me)

Comment: Yes, I used the same process for them and made them in the same step.
In Web8.5, if I select all items and click "Finish Activity", then there is a popup for the first item for me to select the Next Activity, and after I click the "Finish" button, the Finish Activity dialog for the second item will appear to let me select the Next Activity.